# Chainlink config error when running job on node

Tags: chainlink

I'm a bit new to this so apologies in advance if this question is bit vague or ill-defined, but I'm trying to set up a new Chainlink OCR node and add a job to it.  I have the node running and can successfully add a job but almost immediately see the error:

```
TrackConfig: error during LatestConfigDetails()
```

Has anyone experienced this, or know even what config details it's referring to?  I'm not sure where to even start trying to trouble shoot.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Typically, this means that there is an issue with the OCR configuration on-chain, or you ETH node is out of sync.

Please test your node is up to date.